# jQuery .hide works, but .show doesn't

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a table which I need to show and hide up to 9 tr's of a table in groups of 3.  I have loop through a single tr 9 times to produce all 9.  The .hide works, but the .show does not And the jquery doesn't break midway through (I have put alert() all through out the code and even used alert() to display which attendeerow I am trying to show or hide and the values are correct.

here is the snippet which creates the tr's

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="9" step="1">


        <tbody id="attendeeRow<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#693505">
            <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="185" align="right">*Attendee <cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput> Name<br /></td>
                  <td><span id="sprytextfield100<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>">
                    <input name="attendeeName<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>" type="text" class="form" size="35" value="" />
                    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="right">*Attendee <cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput> Title<br /></td>
                  <td><span id="sprytextfield101<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>">
                    <input name="attendeeTitle<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>" type="text" class="form" size="35" value="" />
                    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td align="right">*Attendee <cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput> Company</td>
                  <td><span id="sprytextfield102<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>">
                    <input name="attendeeCompany<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>" type="text" class="form" size="35" value="" />
                    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="right">*Attendee <cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput> Email</td>
                  <td><span id="sprytextfield103<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>">
                  <input name="attendeeEmail<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>" type="text" class="form" size="35" value="" />
                  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg"></span></span></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </cfloop>

        <!---- comment: this bottom part is what allows the user to show or hide the elements, I just use the div with an id="counter" to keep track of where I am.--->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#693505" class="form">
                <div id="counter" style="visibility:hidden;">0</div>
                <div id="additional3">[+] Click here to register an additional 3 attendees</div>
                <div id="subtract3">[+] Click here to remove the last 3 attendees</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

And here is the jquery;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

for (loopIndex = 1; loopIndex <= 9; loopIndex++)
{

    var currentRow = "attendeeRow" + loopIndex;

    var currentName = "attendeeName" + loopIndex;
    var currentTitle = "attendeeTitle" + loopIndex;
    var currentCompany = "attendeeCompany" + loopIndex;
    var currentEmail = "attendeeEmail" + loopIndex;



    $("#"+currentRow).hide();

    $("#"+currentName).val("--");
    $("#"+currentTitle).val("--");
    $("#"+currentCompany).val("--");
    $("#"+currentEmail).val("a@b.c");

}


$("#subtract3").hide(); 
$("#additional3").show();

$("#additional3").live("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var start = $("#counter").text(); 
    var increment = "3";
    var end = parseInt(start) + parseInt(increment); 


    for (loopIndex = start; loopIndex <= end; loopIndex++)
    {
        var currentRow = "attendeeRow" + loopIndex;

        var currentName = "attendeeName" + loopIndex;
        var currentTitle = "attendeeTitle" + loopIndex;
        var currentCompany = "attendeeCompany" + loopIndex;
        var currentEmail = "attendeeEmail" + loopIndex;

        alert("#"+currentRow);
        $("#currentRow").show();

        $("#"+currentName).val("");

        $("#"+currentTitle).val("");

        $("#"+currentCompany).val("");
        $("#"+currentEmail).val("");

    }
    $("#counter").text(end);
    if(start >= 6){
        $("#additional3").hide();

    }
    if(start >= 3){
        $("#subtract3").show();

    }

});

$("#subtract3").live("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var end = $("#counter").text(); 
    var increment = "3";
    var start = parseInt(start) - parseInt(increment); 


    for (loopIndex = start; loopIndex <= end; loopIndex++)
    {
        var currentRow = "attendeeRow" + loopIndex;

        var currentName = "attendeeName" + loopIndex;
        var currentTitle = "attendeeTitle" + loopIndex;
        var currentCompany = "attendeeCompany" + loopIndex;
        var currentEmail = "attendeeEmail" + loopIndex;



        $("#"+currentRow).hide();

        $("#"+currentName).val("--");
        $("#"+currentTitle).val("--");
        $("#"+currentCompany).val("--");
        $("#"+currentEmail).val("a@b.c");

    }
    $("#counter").text(start);


    if(start >= 6){
        $("#additional3").hide();

    }
    if(start >= 3){
        $("#subtract3").show();
    }

});
});
```

Comment: FYI, .live() has been deprecated in favor of .delegate() or .on() depending on your version of jQuery.

Comment: And here's a really good article about the difference and how to use the newer style: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Comment: Is that cold fusion code?  jQuery works on the rendered output, perhaps you should post that.  Better yet, make a jsFiddle.

Comment: Maybe it is depreciated, but that is not the issue here.  The event handlers are working because I am hitting the code.  However thank you for letting me know about this, I did not know before.  I definitely will read into that.

Comment: Yeah it is cold fusion, how would I use the coldfusion code in jsfiddle?  would I Have to copy and paste the code minus coldfusion multiple times?  Reguardless I'm going to start doing that now.

Comment: @d.lanza38 Best way would be just to just view the coldfusion output in a web browser and view the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this...

```
alert("#"+currentRow);
$("#currentRow").show();
```

is meant to be this...

```
alert("#" + currentRow);
$("#" + currentRow).show();
```

You're alerting the concatenation, but not doing the concatenation for the DOM selection.

Comment: That will do it lol.  I spent way too long on this, thank youam not i am

Answer (score 2):

In your `#subtract3` click event, you have a copy paste error.

```
var start = parseInt(start) - parseInt(increment);
```

should be

```
var start = parseInt(end) - parseInt(increment);
```

Additionally, you could use `.click()` instead of `.live("click"` since you aren't replacing those elements.

Comment: Thank You, After fixing the initial error I realized the .hide after the initial .hide wasn't working properly.